# Hierarchical storage management Windows

Tags: windows-7, usb, hard-disk

Is there any Hierarchical Storage Management (HSM) products running on Windows priced at consumer level, or even better free/opensource?

Idealy it would

- Virtualise multiple storage devices and present a single volume.
- Tolerate failures, e.g. if one of the drives being used is unplugged any content on it will in inaccessible, but the overall virtual volume should remain accessible.
- Define policies to manage data between physical disks (pd), e.g. files from pd1 not accessed within some period are moved to pd2.
- Manually moving between pd's should also be possible.

It seems that this type of product is only available for the enterprise, but I would be happy to learn of a consumer level alternative.